# Definable sets in set theory

Tags: logic, set-theory

A formula $\phi$ with a single free variable in the language of set theory with a single free-variable defines a set $x$ if $\phi(x)$ holds but $\phi(y)$ does not hold if $y \neq x$.

Is every set definable by a  $\Sigma_1$ formula countable?

Is every set definable by a $\Pi_1$ formula countable?

Comment: Are you aware that this is not the standard definition of "definable"? What you are asking is about the definability of $\{x\}$.

Comment: @martin.koeberl In a structure $M$, an element $m$ is definable if for some formula $\varphi(x)$, we have $M\models\varphi(a)$ iff $a=m$ for all $a\in M$. This matches the OP's definition where the *set* $x$ is viewed as an *element* of the structure $(V,\in)$. So there's a conflation here between two notions of "definable set": definable set in the usual sense, or definable element-which-is-a-set.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm aware of this. But I think OP is interested in exactly the case $(V,\in)$  where -- at least to my knowledge -- the standard is to talk about definability of a set (and OP even refers to "a set $x$"). If one is interested in the other definability one normally talks about definability of the "singleton ..." as far as I recall. I didn't say there is anything wrong but the wording is slightly nonstandard and I wanted to make sure OP is aware of that. (I guess I could have been more verbose in my first comment.)

Comment: @martin.koeberl Sorry, I wrote my comment poorly - I definitely didn't mean to imply that you were unaware of that. I've unfortunately heard "definable set" used in *both* ways, with some frequency. This is sometimes justified though: $a$ and $\{a\}$ (as collections) are definable at roughly the same level. E.g. if $\{a\}$ has a $\Gamma$-definition $\varphi$, then the collection $a$ can be defined as $\{x: \exists y(\varphi(y)\wedge x\in y)\}$ or as $\{x: \forall y(\varphi(y)\implies x\in y)\}$, so $a$ is $\Delta_1(\Gamma)$-definable. Going from $a$ to $\{a\}$ is slightly worse: (cont'd)

Comment: If the collection $a$ is defined by a $\Gamma$-formula $\varphi$, then $\{a\}$ is the set of $x$ such that $\forall y(\varphi(y)\iff y\in x)$, so is $\Pi_1(\Gamma)$; but I don't see a way to get a $\Sigma_1(\Gamma)$ definition immediately.

Comment: I believe that $V_{\omega+1}$ is definable by a $\Pi_{1}$-formula in the sense of the OP, but is not countable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber No worries, no offense taken. I guess, I was just lucky (or ignorant) enough to not be exposed to these confusions so far. I'd be curious whether this appears printed anywhere. In any case, our discussion might be fruitful for future readers for this questions. And thanks for pointing me towards the interdefinability of $a$ and $\{a\}$, I just started to wonder about that.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Not ignorant, definitely lucky. It's a terrible bit of terminological confusion. I try to force myself to use "definable collection" or "definable object" in this context, but I often slip up.

Comment: Regarding the terminology, the OP's usage seems to be the standard model-theoretic notion for what it means to say that an element is definable in a structure, and this is the notion that I have used, for example, in my papers on point-wise definable models (http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/). The model theorists also of course have a concept for what it means to say that a subset of a model is definable. The two notions can become conflated for the models of set theory, since every element can also be construed as a subset.

Comment: @MartinS: Not quite a descriptive set theory question, since it is about definability of sets in the universe in the language of set theory; and not sets of reals (in second order arithmetic).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the correction of tags.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, don't you regard the  Lévy reflection theorem as part of descriptive set theory?

Comment: @JDH: I'm not a descriptive set theorist, but I don't think so.

Comment: I don't subscribe to the idea that there are precise delineations of the subject areas, but I have always thought of the Lévy reflection theorem as an easier weaker version of Shoenfield absoluteness, which is certainly part of descriptive set theory, and therefore I would be fine with someone who wanted to take Lévy reflection as part of that subject.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes, every set definable by a $\Sigma_1$-formula is countable. This is an immediate consequence of the Levy reflection theorem, which states that $H_{\omega_1}\prec_{\Sigma_1} V$. So the assertion that there is a set satisfying that definition is also $\Sigma_1$ and therefore must be in $H_{\omega_1}$ and hence it is countable.

(The Levy reflection theorem itself is not difficult to prove: fix a witness for any $\Sigma_1$ property, and then take a countable elementary substructure inside a bigger $H_\theta$, and collapse it. The collapse of the witness will also witness the property, since any transitive set is correct about $\Delta_0$ assertions.)

For the second question, the answer is no, since $x=P(\omega)$ is defined by the $\Pi_1$ formula asserting first that every element of $x$ is a subset of $\omega$ (that part is $\Delta_0$) and secondly that every $z$ that is a subset of $\omega$ is an element of $x$. We don't need $\omega$ as a parameter, since it is definable as the unique limit ordinal not containing any limit ordinals as elements, and that is $\Delta_0$, so it doesn't increase the complexity of the definition of $P(\omega)$.